# Merge 2 Autofac containers into one

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

is there a way i can merge 2 autoface container into 1?
I mean that all registrations from both containers will be included in the new one
Alternatively it could be upgrade one of them with the other

For example:

```
public IContainer Merge(IContainer container1, IContainer container2)
{
     return ???;
}
```

I've tried iterating over "container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations" and by using containerBuilder registering components and upgrading the second container but for some reason there were some conflicts

```
    Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> The provided instance has already been used in an activation request. Did you combine a provided instance with non-root/single-instance lifetime/sharing? (See inner exception for details.)
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : The provided instance has already been used in an activation request. Did you combine a provided instance with non-root/single-instance lifetime/sharing?
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, ref Object instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context)
   at Bootstrap.Bootstrapper.CreatePersistentTimerAsyncExecuter(IContainer container)
   at Bootstrap.Bootstrapper.Monitor(IContainer container)
   at Bootstrap.Bootstrapper.Boot(Assembly[] assemblies)
   at Soluto.Telemetry.Processing.Core.IntegrationTests.TelemetryProcessingBootstrapperTests.Boot_With2TelemetryHandlersInAssembly_ResolvesSubscriberWithItsHandlers() in TelemetryProcessingBootstrapperTests.cs: line 88
--InvalidOperationException
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.ProvidedInstance.ProvidedInstanceActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.<Execute>b__0()
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers guys,
eventually i did something more specific for my needs:

```
public void Merge(this IContainer container1, IContainer container2)
{ 
    var newBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    newBuilder.RegisterInstance(container2.Resolve<ISomeService1>()).AsImplementedInterfaces();
    newBuilder.RegisterInstance(container2.Resolve<ISomeService2>()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

    newBuilder.Update(container1);
    return container1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom `IRegistrationSource`. This interface contains a `RegistrationsFor` method that return a list of `IComponentRegistration` for a specific `IService`

```
public class CrossContainerRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public CrossContainerRegistrationSource(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        this._componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    private readonly IComponentContext _componentContext;

    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, 
        Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        return this._componentContext.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(service);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this :

```
container2.ComponentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new CrossContainerRegistrationSource(container1));
```

But be careful with this solution it may introduce issue when you use complex scope scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

```
var existingContainer = new ContainerBuilder();
// Add registrations to existing container.

var newContainerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
// Add registrations to new container.

newContainterBuilder.Update(existingContainer);
```

The `update` method essentially merges the contents of the `existingContainer` into the `newContainerBuilder`.

#### EDIT - If using an IContainer

If you have already built your `ContainerBuilder` into an `IContainer` the `Update` method of the `ContainerBuilder` is able to accept an `IContainer` as input. But in this case the already built container will now contain all the registrations and the new `ContainerBuilder` can go out of scope.

```
var builtContainer = existingContainer.Build();

var newContainerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
// Add registrations to new container.

newContainterBuilder.Update(builtContainer);
```

Comment: in your example 'existingContainer' is a ContainerBuilder. what i have is a IContainer instance.
What would you do in this case?

Comment: @danfromisrael I would do exactly the same. The `update` method is overloaded so that it takes either an `IComponentRegistry` or an `IContainer`

Comment: @Stephan Ross thanks for the answer. I have 2 ready IContainers i need to combine into 1. Edited the question and added example

Comment: @danfromisrael Ok this is slightly more different. Can I ask how you have gotten into the situation where you have 2 different containers. As you can guess this isn't where you want to be. If this is because you have initialized two separate instances and want to merge them I think it may be good to look into Autofac `modules` as they allow separability but will also merge into one container at build. If this is not the case I think you are in a state where you need to look at your design; more details would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that `Update()` is marked obsolete in newer versions of Autofac and should not be used. See https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811#issuecomment-270246744 for more clarification.

Some of the recommendations listed to get around this issue is:

- Pass Around ContainerBuilder Instead of IContainer
- Add Registrations to Child Scopes
- Use Lambdas
- Use Modules
- Use Conditional Registrations (new in 4.4.0)

Basically.. don't end up with 2 containers if possible.